# Передать данные из c# в delphi

Tags: c#, delphi, ipc

Запущено два приложения. Одно на c#, второе на delphi
Необходимо передать число из c# в delphi.

Как сделать даже не знаю, гуглил, говорят через dll или оперативную память, запись и считывание файла.

Comment: И что вам мешает?

Comment: да впринципе на данный момент кода нет, хотелось бы проконсультироваться, чтобы не изобретать велосипед

Comment: как вариант отправить окну сообщение?

Comment: Есть следующие технологии синхронизации: Win-Message, Pipes (Named pipes конкретнее), Socket, MailSlot, Разделяемая память. Выбирайте любой - используйте.

Comment: убрал из текста лишнее, а также вопрос «а как лучше?» — такой вопрос, подразумевающий опрос мнений, здесь [не стоит задавать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Я использую для обмена инфой между приложениями оконные сообщения  и сокеты. Проще всего sendmessage и внутри формы на delphi сделать обработчик сообщения.

Comment: а есть у кого код поделиться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал так:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;

class ProgramSend
{
    public const int WM_COPYDATA = 0x004A;
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct MyStruct
    {
        public double coins;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
        public string status;
    }    

    public static IntPtr IntPtrAlloc<T>(T param)
    {
        IntPtr retval = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(param));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(param, retval, false);
        return (retval);
    }

    public static void IntPtrFree(IntPtr preAllocated)
    {
        if (IntPtr.Zero == preAllocated) throw (new Exception("Go Home"));
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(preAllocated); preAllocated = IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct COPYDATASTRUCT
    {
        public IntPtr dwData;       // Specifies data to be passed
        public int cbData;          // Specifies the data size in bytes
        public IntPtr lpData;       // Pointer to data to be passed
    }

    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    public class NativeMethod
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg,
            IntPtr wParam, ref COPYDATASTRUCT lParam);    

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
    }
}

public static class MyCalss
{
    public static System.String MyFunc(string sMsg)
    {

        IntPtr hTargetWnd = ProgramSend.NativeMethod.FindWindow(null, "CCDemo");
        if (hTargetWnd == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to find the \"ReceiverMainForm\" window",
                "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        try
        {
            ProgramSend.COPYDATASTRUCT cds = new ProgramSend.COPYDATASTRUCT();
            cds.dwData = (IntPtr)1; //some data
            cds.cbData = sMsg.Length + 1;
            cds.lpData = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(sMsg);

            ProgramSend.NativeMethod.SendMessage(hTargetWnd, ProgramSend.WM_COPYDATA, IntPtr.Zero, ref cds);

            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(cds.lpData);

            int result = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            if (result != 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format(
                    "SendMessage(WM_COPYDATA) failed w/err 0x{0:X}", result));
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            //Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pMyStruct);
        }
        return "done";
    }

}
```

На делфи:

```
type
  TMyRecord = packed record
    coins: Double;
    status: string[255];
  end;
  PMyRecord = ^TMyRecord;

procedure TFMain.WMCOPYDATA(var msg: TWMCopyData);
var
  coins: Double;
  status: String[255];
  sText: String;
begin
status:=Pansichar(msg.CopyDataStruct.lpData);
coins := msg.CopyDataStruct.dwData;
ShowMessage('Msg: ' + status + ' Number: ' + FloatToStr(coins));
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Примерно так например (средствами SendMessage WM_COPYDATA):
Отправка:

```
Type
  TSendForm = Class(TForm)
    btnSend: TButton;
    edtNumber: TEdit;
    procedure btnSendClick(Sender: TObject);
  Private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  Public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  End;

Const
  CMD_SETNUMBER = 1; //Задаем ID команды

Var
  SendForm: TSendForm;

Implementation

{$R *.dfm}

Procedure TSendForm.btnSendClick(Sender: TObject);
Var
  CDS: TCopyDataStruct;
Begin
  //Устанавливаем тип команды
  CDS.dwData := CMD_SETNUMBER;
  //Устанавливаем длину передаваемых данных
  CDS.cbData := Length(edtNumber.Text) + 1;
  //Выделяем память буфера для передачи данных
  GetMem(CDS.lpData, CDS.cbData);
  Try
    //Копируем данные в буфер
    StrPCopy(CDS.lpData, AnsiString(edtNumber.Text));
    //Отсылаем сообщение в окно с заголовком StringReceiver
    SendMessage(FindWindow(Nil, 'Receiver'), WM_COPYDATA, Handle, Integer(@CDS));
  Finally
    //Высвобождаем буфер
    FreeMem(CDS.lpData, CDS.cbData);
  End;
End;

End.
```

Обработка:

```
Type
  TRecvForm = Class(TForm)
    mLog: TMemo;
  Private
    FNumber: Integer;
    //Обработчик сообщения WM_COPYDATA
    Procedure WMCopyData(Var MessageData: TWMCopyData); Message WM_COPYDATA;
  Public
    Property Number: Integer Read FNumber Write FNumber;
  End;

Const
  CMD_SETNUMBER = 1;

Var
  RecvForm: TRecvForm;

Implementation

{$R *.dfm}

Procedure TRecvForm.WMCopyData(Var MessageData: TWMCopyData);
Begin
  If MessageData.CopyDataStruct.dwData = CMD_SETNUMBER Then Begin
    Try
      Number := StrToInt(String(PAnsiChar((MessageData.CopyDataStruct.lpData))));
    Except
      On E: Exception Do Begin
        mLog.Lines.Append(Format('Ошибка: %s', [E.Message]));
        MessageData.Result := 0;
        Exit;
      End;
    End;
    mLog.Lines.Append(Format('Получено число: %d', [Number]));
    MessageData.Result := 1;
  End
  Else
    MessageData.Result := 0;
End;

End.
```

Соответственно одно из них реализуете на C#